# Use an iPhone as a bluetooth headset for a Mac?

Tags: macos, mac, iphone, audio, bluetooth

Is there any way, such as an iPhone app, that will let me connect my iPhone to my iMac via bluetooth, so that the iMac pushes all audio through the iPhone?

Specifically, what I'm looking to do is be able to watch movies on my iMac with the sound being played through my iPhone & in turn the ear buds.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Airfoil For Mac](http://www.rogueamoeba.com/airfoil/) and the Airfoil speakers app for iPhone.  This works over WiFi though.  And the Mac program costs $25 USD. The Demo of Airfoil has no usage limit but overlays noise on broadcasts longer that 10 minutes.

Comment: Not a bad idea, I think Airfoil will introduce lag if your not using their video player.  http://www.rogueamoeba.com/support/knowledgebase/?showArticle=AirfoilVideoPlayer

Comment: Oh, sorry I didn't see this. It comes free with Airfoil though so it wouldn't be that hard to get a hold of.

Comment: I thought Airfoil first syncs its lag between all clients and makes sure that "lag" isn't introduced in your music.